# imacro script to run loops and enter values in form

Tags: ajax, forms, automation, imacros

I want to create a simple marcro file which will increment the form value every time.

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:mobileNumber CONTENT=QESSARWF50
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=TXT:Proceed
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:mobileNumber CONTENT=QESSARWF51
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=TXT:Proceed

I want to repeat this query for about 100 times with increment. How can I do it.

one clue :

We can use .csv file to get the values.
But I don't know how to get it. Can Any one code it ?

Answer (score 0):

View this example:

```
SET !DATASOURCE  yourFile.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
SET !VAR! {{!COL1}}
```

For more information see: [wiki](http://wiki.imacros.net/Command_Reference)

Comment: hello @shugar 
I'm trying this code

TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
CMDLINE !DATASOURCE 
SET !DATASOURCE C:\users.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMN 1
'Start at line 2 to skip the header in the file
SET !LOOP 1
'Increase the current position in the file with each loop
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
' Fill web form

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:mobileNumber CONTENT={{!COL1}}
`

It gives me an error "NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED: Component returned failure code: 0x80520015 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED) [nsIFileInputStream.init], line 3 (Error code: -1001)"

Comment: Hello. (1) Delete or comment the line 3: ‘CMDLINE !DATASOURCE’. (2) Check the presence of your file. (3) Write ‘SET !LOOP 2’ if you really want to skip the header in the file.